# How do i show the name of a column as a row data using a sql query?

Tags: mysql

I am quite inexperienced with the query writing.

I have a table like this,

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+    
| id | name   | Character1 | Character2 | Character3 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+      
| 1  | A      |     1      |      0     |     0      | 
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------+   
| 2  | B      |     0      |      1     |     0      |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

i want to make a query where the result would show me like this, where i put a condition to search a name,

```
+----+--------+---------------+
| id  | name  | Character     |
+----+--------+---------------+
| 1   | A     | Character 1   |
+----+--------+---------------+
```

What will be the query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `CASE` expression:

```
select id, name,
  case 1
    when Character1 then 'Character1'
    when Character2 then 'Character2'
    when Character3 then 'Character3'
  end Character
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
select id, name, case 1
   WHEN characters1 = 1 THEN characters1
   WHEN characters2 = 1 THEN characters2
   WHEN YourColumn = 1 THEN YourColumn //if you have more
Else 'no 1' END
    from YourTableName where name LIKE '%searhname%'
```

Replace **YourTableName** above as your *real table name*, meanwhile `searchname` is what you or user is going to type in and search
**YourColumn** will be `character2` and `3`... or many more :)

For more information about `LIKE`, such as the difference between `'%name'` and `'name%'`, you may view this link [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/)

Comment: In the 2nd table, "Character" will show the name from the 1st table column if it finds a value 1. For example, if i put a condition "Where name=A", it will check from the 1st table which column has value 1. It will show the name of that column.

Comment: hmm, seems like there is another condition there, see my updated answer

Comment: In my case, All the values in Name column will definitely have one of the character. Anyway 2nd one also works. Thanks a lot. :)